# How to install magento 2.1.3 theme

Tags: magento2, theme

I am new to magento 2.1
Could you please tell me how to install magento 2.1.3 via composer or manually and what is the structure of a theme for magento 2?

Answer (score 0):

Upload the theme file unzip file and keep theme folder inside `app/design/frontend`

Run the command script

```
php -f bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-conent:deploy
```

clear cache

If theme show in list themes. Go to  `Content -> Design -> Configuration section` in the admin choose "Your theme". Save the change. The step will apply the theme for frontend of your store.

Answer (score 0):

After running "php bin/magento setup:static-conent:deploy" I received this error:
`[InvalidArgumentException]

  There are no commands defined in the "setup:static-conent" namespace.

  Did you mean one of these?

      setup:static-content

      setup

      setup:config

      setup:cron

      setup:db-data

      setup:db-schema

      setup:db

      setup:di

      setup:performance

      setup:store-config`